# Output of a simulation in Matlab involving draws from normal distributions

Tags: matlab

I am a confused on the output I should expect from the following simulation in Matlab

```
n_m=1000; 
n_w=1000; 

%Construct a vector eta by drawing n_m*n_w+n_m realisations from N(0,1) and then add n_w zeros
eta=randn(n_m*n_w+n_m,1); %(n_m*n_w+n_m)x1
eta=[eta; zeros(n_w,1)]; %(n_m*n_w+n_m+n_w)x1 

%Construct a vector zeta by drawing n_m*n_w+n_w realisations from N(0,1) and then add n_m zeros
zeta=randn(n_m*n_w+n_w,1); %(n_w*n_m+n_w)x1
zeta=[zeta(1:n_m*n_w); zeros(n_m,1); zeta(n_m*n_w+1:end)]; %(n_m*n_w+n_m+n_w)x1 

%Compare the empirical cdf of eta+zeta, of a N(0,1), of a N(0,2)
etazeta=eta+zeta;
benchmark1=randn(10000,1); %N(0,1)
benchmark2=normrnd(0,sqrt(2),10000,1); %N(0,2)
ecdf(etazeta)
hold on
ecdf(benchmark1)
hold on
ecdf(benchmark2)
legend('my', 'N(0,1)', 'N(0,2)')
```

What we can see is that the empirical cdf of `etazeta` is close to the empirical cdf of a `N(0,2)`.

I am confused on why that is the case: since I add a bunch of zeros to the vectors `eta` and `zeta`, how can it be that `eta+zeta` looks like a `N(0,2)` as if the zeros weren't there?

Comment: What I see in `etazeta` is 998,000 random values from a distribution N(0,2), and 2,000 random values from a distribution N(0,1). Taken together, the 2,000 values will not change the CDF by much at all. What were you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a mathematical point of view, the sum `Z` of two normally distributed variables `X` and `Y` is defined as follows (refer to [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) for more details):

[image: Maths]

I modified your script setting both `n_m` and `n_w` to `10` in order to simplify my demonstration, but the outcome is basically unchanged. Let's start by taking a deeper look at the composition of the `eta` and `zeta` vectors produced by your code:

```
eta  = 110 x N(0,1) + 10 x ZEROS
zeta = 100 x N(0,1) + 10 x ZEROS + 10 x N(0,1)
```

In order to have a clearer view of this composition, let's break it down into equally sized pieces:

```
eta  = 100 x N(0,1) + 10 x N(0,1) + 10 x ZEROS
zeta = 100 x N(0,1) + 10 x ZEROS  + 10 x N(0,1)
```

Since `eta` and `zeta` are summed together, the result of their summation is:

```
eta     = 100 x N(0,1)            + 10 x N(0,1) + 10 x ZEROS
zeta    = 100 x N(0,1)            + 10 x ZEROS  + 10 x N(0,1)

etazeta = 100 x [N(0,1) + N(0,1)] + 10 x N(0,1) + 10 x N(0,1)
etazeta = 100 x N(0,2)            + 20 x N(0,1)
```

In `etazeta`, we basically have:

- `100` values with mean `0` and variance `2` (this is because the
  first 100 values of both vectors are normally distributed with mean
  `0` and variance `1`, hence `N(0,1) + N(0,1) = N(0+0,1+1) = N(0,2)`)
- `20` values with mean `0` and variance `1` (the `0` filled vectors balance both sides of the last part of `eta` and `zeta`)

If we calculate the average mean and variance of `etazeta`, we have:

```
AVG(mean)     = (100 * 0 + 20 * 0) / 120 = 0
AVG(variance) = (100 * 2 + 20 * 1) / 120 = 1.83
```

Hence, `etazeta` is much closer to an `N(0,2)` variable than to an `N(0,1)` variable (but still differs from both). The more you increase your `n_m` and `n_w` values, the more `etazeta` becomes similar to an `N(0,2)` variable, converging.

Hence, there is nothing wrong in both Matlab computations and your code.